How to reference a subsection or a subsubsection when both letters and numbers are used
I think there must already be an answer to this but I haven't found a result from my search.
I have a document where the sections have arabic numerals (1,2,3), the subsections have uppercase letters (A, B, C), and the subsubsections have lowercase Roman numerals (i, ii, iii), which I assume arises from the style file I am using (from a template for a particular publication). If I cross-reference the second subsubsection of the first subsection of the third section, labelled \label{that_subsubsection}, I guess I would want it to say S3.A.ii, where the S is that fancy character you get from typing \S. But if I type \S\ref{that_subsubsection}, I get S3.1.2, with arabic numerals throughout.
Is there any way to get it to understand that I want the cross-reference with the same lettering/numbering that is used in the document? Thanks.

Can you share the document class that you are using? Without this, it is not easy to answer.

normally that should work out-of-the-box. So your document or template is doing something unusual.

Please tell us more about the mysterious yet intriguing "template for a particular publication" you say you using. E.g., is it availalbe online?

I'm using the article class with the template for POMA, and poma_style.sty, found at https://pubs.aip.org/asa/poma/pages/manuscript

In the style file you are using, they only redefine the look of section titles using the titlesec package:
\definecolor{ASAblue}{RGB}{51,51,153}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\thesection.}}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\Alph{subsection}.}}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalsize}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\roman{subsubsection}.}}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{#1}}

This leaves the respective counters untouched, therefore when you use them for reference you get the 'arabic' values.
A solution that works in this case does two things:

Redefines the counters of \subsection and \subsubsection to look as they must in the respective titles; now the respective \Alph or \roman must be removed from \titleformat.
Arranges for the references to produce all the levels of section numbering by redefining the \p@subsection and \p@subsubsection commands which produce the prefix when referencing subsections and subsubsections, respectively.

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection.}
\makeatother

\definecolor{ASAblue}{RGB}{51,51,153}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\thesection.}}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\thesubsection}.}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalsize}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{\thesubsubsection}.}{1em}{\color{ASAblue}\textbf{#1}}


Awesome! Thank you so much!
